# Count all special custom fields per post of a category (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

With this script my special custom field "Nickname" is counted only once, also if these field is available twice or more in a post.

Is there a way to count all special custom fields called "Nickname" in a post?

Thats the script:

```
<?php
$posts_with_nickname = get_posts(array(
        'category__in' => array(2,5),
        'meta_key' => 'Nickname',
        'showposts' => -1,
));

printf('I have %d posts with "Nickname"!', count($posts_with_nickname));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [meta_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

```
<?php
$posts_with_nickname = get_posts(
    'category__in' => array(2,5),
    'meta_query'   => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'Nickname',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
        ),
    ),
    'showposts'    => -1,
);

printf('I have %d posts with "Nickname"!', count($posts_with_nickname));
```

Comment: Big thx for support, but I get an syntaxerror with your code ;(

Comment: Ok, I have fixed it, but I think it doesn´t count like the way I need, because it counts the posts with special meta, not meta (custom fields) itself.